# MLRun, Role issue - Read only mode for Events, Identity, Grafana, etc

Tags: access-control, user-permissions, user-roles, mlrun

I'm having trouble with accessing the typically admin parts of the Iguazio platform, like 'Services', 'Identity', 'Clusters', 'Grafana', ... but in read-only mode.

When I used 'Application Read Only' and 'Project Read Only', I couldn't see everything and when I used, for example 'Application Admin' role, I was without Read-only and could change everything.

[image]

Did you solve the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use new role 'IT Admin Read Only' from Iguazio platform 3.5.4 (release date, 10 September 2023) see original [description](https://www.iguazio.com/docs/latest-release/users-and-security/security/#predefined-management-policies)

> **IT Admin Read Only** — read-only view of the Clusters, Storage, and
> Events pages, and from the App Cluster page has access to the Grafana
> dashboard of the app cluster metrics. See more information about logs
> in Logging, Monitoring, and Debugging.